# Use ag in ctrlp + vim

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I want to use ag (silver searcher) with ctrlp and vim.
I have this in my .vimrc:

```
if executable("ag")
    set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'
endif

let g:ctrlp_show_hidden = 1

set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*/.tmp/*,*/.sass-cache/*,*/node_modules/*,*.keep,*.DS_Store,*/.git/*
```

I want ctrlp to include hidden files but those are hidden. If I add `-u` to the ag command it shows all hidden files but doesn't respect the wildignore or .gitignore. Is it possible to make it respect these?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? or do you need additional information?

Comment: It sure does! Forgot to mark your answer as accepted, sorry about that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you are using a custom finder via `ctrlp_user_command` several options, including `ctrlp_show_hidden` `ctrlp_custom_ignore` and vim's `wildignore` patterns, are not used by CtrlP ([see documentation](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt)).

> **g:ctrlp_show_hidden**
>
> ...
>
> Note: does not apply when a command defined with
>   |g:ctrlp_user_command| is being used.
>
> **g:ctrlp_custom_ignore**
>
> ...
>
> Note #1: by default, |wildignore| and |g:ctrlp_custom_ignore| only
>   apply when |globpath()| is used to scan for files, thus these options
>   do not apply when a command defined with |g:ctrlp_user_command| is
>   being used.

So you are left at the mercy of your searching tool, in this case, ag. Fortunately you can do a couple things that should give you the behavior you want.

To get your hidden dotfiles to appear, but still respect `ignore` files, use the `--hidden` option for ag:

`let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden -g ""'`

Now for defining patterns to ignore, you can use ag's own ignore file [.agignore](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/wiki/Advanced-Usage). This can be a per directory or a global one that ag will check on each run. You place that in your home dir `~/.agignore`.

I understand it can be nice to have vims `wildignore` take care of patterns, but with `.agignore` you get the bonus of those restrictions when using ag from the cli. If you want to search all files just use the `ag -u` command you mentioned to bypass any `ignore` files.

As a final tidbit, there is a Dictionary format you can use to define `g:ctrlp_user_command` which contains an `ignore` key that will make CtrlP use `wildignore` patterns. However, I've never tried this and the documentation points out a potential performance hit. You might try this method if you don't like my other proposed solution ([see documentation](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L302-L352)).

> Note #3: unless the |Dictionary| format is used and 'ignore' is
>   defined and set to 1, the |wildignore| and |g:ctrlp_custom_ignore|
>   options do not apply when these custom commands are being used. When
>   not present, 'ignore' is set to 0 by default to retain the performance
>   advantage of using external commands.

Comment: from where did you know the "" part at the end of ag command for ctrlp?

Comment: The thing I always miss when setting up on a new computer is that you must place the `.agignore` in the _home directory_ (i.e. `~/.agignore`) not in the root of your application.