# How to allow vim ctrlp plugin to find files that start with dot

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to be able to ctrlp into `.gitignore` and `.circleci/` etc and I can't figure out what's preventing me from opening files that start with a `.` I've tried disabling all customizations for ctrlp and doing a `:PluginUpdate` as well but I can't figure out what's going on.

This directory I'm in has a `.gitignore` but it's not showing up:

[image]

Here's my ctrlp variables from vim:

```
: echo copy(g:)->filter('v:key =~# "^ctrlp"')
{'ctrlp_newcache': 0,
 'ctrlp_map': '<c-p>',
 'ctrlp_alltags': [],
 'ctrlp_mruf_include': '',
 'ctrlp_mruf_max': 250,
 'ctrlp_allmixes': {},
 'ctrlp_status_func': {
    'prog': 'PowerlineStatuslineCallback_ctrlp_prog',
    'main': 'PowerlineStatuslineCallback_ctrlp_main'},
 'ctrlp_mruf_relative': 0,
 'ctrlp_cmd': 'CtrlP',
 'ctrlp_mruf_exclude': '',
 'ctrlp_mruf_case_sensitive': 1,
 'ctrlp_lines': [],
 'ctrlp_mruf_save_on_update': 1,
 'ctrlp_ext_vars': [],
 'ctrlp_alldirs': [],
 'ctrlp_allfiles': ['bashrc',
     'bin/gus',
     'Brewfile',
     'bash/env',
     'readme.md',
     'osx/hacks',
     'bash/config',
     'bash/aliases',
     'git/gitconfig',
     'settings/sync.sh',
     'bash/functions/focus.sh'],
 'ctrlp_builtins': 2,
 'ctrlp_buftags': {}}
```

Any ideas on how to debug why ctrlp isn't showing my hidden/dot files or how to debug this?

Comment: What does the plugin's  documentation say about  the matter?

Answer (score 3):

Searching the docs (again, thanks) [I found this source file with a setting](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/blob/f68f4d00b9c99d0d711bfde3b071f0dafd249901/doc/ctrlp.txt#L238) `let g:ctrlp_show_hidden=1` but it didn't fix my problem.

I had to also force clear the cache with `:CtrlPClearAllCaches`, and now it works!

While this solves my immediate problem I also found a related SO post that mentions that this setting does nothing in some cases when defining a custom search script like using `ag` [Use ag in ctrlp + vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285751/use-ag-in-ctrlp-vim)

Comment: You can also press F5 (default binding) while the CtrlP pane is open to refresh the file listing.

Comment: I don't have F-keys on my laptop. Good to know though.